# How to connect to MSSQL with PHP on linux/lamp?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

Is there a way to connect to MYSQL server on standard hosting cpanel php 5.6 with no possibility to install any new drivers through shell/ssh?

here is my server php PDO config 
[image]

so i have tried different variations of

```
    <?php try {     $pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=my.database.com:1449;dbname=mydb", "myusername", "mypassword");     $result = $pdo->query("select * from mytable"); } catch (PDOException $e) {     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n"; } ?>
```

got Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

```
$con = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net:1433; Database=***; UID=***@***;PWD=***;');
      $result = $con->query('
                             SELECT *
                             FROM ***
                            ');
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        print_r($row);
      }
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source' in /home/benderli/public_html/test/1.php:15 Stack trace: #0 /home/benderli/public_html/test/1.php(15): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver=Fre...') #1 {main} thrown
```

And still no luck. But can connect and get results with XAMP/windows pc with propper mssql dll drivers from MS web site.

Comment: `("dblib:host=Server;dbname=MyDB","username",'pass')`

Comment: @huhu thanks, but still no luck